# Unable to check for visible web element(s) after search

Tags: java, reactjs, selenium

I have a scenario in my feature file that simply opens up a given page, searches for an employee and checks if said employee exists. However, I can't figure out a stale element reference which keeps taunting me.

I have incorporated a few generic wait methods to check for visibility and to verify the presence of an element, but to no avail.

Here's a snippet from my BasePage class:

```
  public void waitForElementToBeClickable(WebElement element) {
    wait.ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class, StaleElementReferenceException.class)
        .pollingEvery(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(element));
}

public void waitForElementToBeVisible(WebElement element) {
    wait.ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class, StaleElementReferenceException.class)
        .pollingEvery(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(element));
}

public void verifyPresenceOfElement(WebElement element) {
    boolean presence = false;
    int attempts = 0;

    while (attempts < 5) {
        try {
            if (element.isDisplayed()) {
                presence = true;
                break;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        attempts++;
    }
}
```

First two methods are simply a wrapper for Selenium's WebDriverWait class. The third one retries to check if element is displayed.

In my page object class I have method that loops through a list of web elements and checks if the text contains a string that matches the argument. Like this:

```
public boolean listOfEmployeeCards(String employee) {
    for (WebElement items : employees) {
        if (items.getText().contains(employee)) {
            verifyPresenceOfElement(items);
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

And in my steps class I do an assert on the actual test step.

The exception is thrown on line 63 in my page object class which is the if statement in listOfEmployeeCards (mentioned above). I'm thinking that I have either misplaced the method verifyPresenceOfElement(), or the entire method is wrong.

I have a similiar scenario which basically filters employees (by clicking on buttons) on the same page with the search functionality, and it works just fine. This scenario also uses the method listOfEmployeeCards(), and I added a quick print to check if verifyPresenceOfElement() is actually triggered at all. And it does seem to be triggered, at least in that scenario.

Quick note, there's an underlying ReactJS app on the page performing all the actions (searching, filtering).

Any ideas? Oh, if I made myself unclear, I'm happy to elaborate.

Comment: You just have to refind all elements from `employees` `List`

Comment: Why not just use an xpath with the employee name with a contains filter to find the appropriate element?

Comment: @RafałLaskowski Well, that is what I intended to do with my verifyPresenceOfElement() method. Do you have a concrete example?

Comment: @Grasshopper Why would I use an XPath when I have an ID available directly from the <div> tag?

Comment: @anigma You are missing the point of `StaleElementReferenceException`. You are not refinding an element with your method. You are simply ignoring it. 
This method accepts a parameter of a `WebElement`. You are passing already stale element to your method. 
You have to use `findElement` and find again your element so your reference is attached to proper `WebElement`. Currently, your reference points to `WebElement` which does DID exist. It has been rebuilt by your application. It might look the same, have the exact same parameters.

Comment: I appreciate the pointers, @RafałLaskowski. Do you happen to have any examples?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed [@RafałLaskowski's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48525008/unable-to-check-for-visible-web-elements-after-search/50430665#comment84045123_48525008) pointers and ended up with the following working code in my page object class:

```
public void searchForEmployee(String text) {
    WebElement results = getDriver().findElement(By.className("fn"));
    if (inputFieldIsEmpty(search)) {
        search.sendKeys(text);
    }
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.stalenessOf(results));
}

public boolean listOfEmployeeCards(String employee) {
    List<String> employeeList = elementToStringList(employees);
    return elementListContainsString(employeeList, employee);
}
```